# What does it mean if the mx record has a different address than the mail dns entry?

Tags: email, dns, mx-record

A web designer friend of mine is moving a customer of hers to a new hosting provider but she wanted me to look at their email setup to make sure that nothing she was doing would affect their email. I did an assortment of MX record and dns record lookups and to me there seems to be something really strange with their mail setup. For example, there are two mx records where I'm used to seeing one (domain names and ip addresses are dummy's just to be safe): Pref: 10 hostname: mx.name.net ip address: 111.222.555.333 and the second Pref: 20 hostname: mx.ct.diffname.net ip address: 111.222.444.222 and neither "name" nor "diffnam" is their domain name. Then the dns entry for mail.theirdomain.net points to an address that's different from either the two addresses pointed to by the mx record.

I haven't setup a mail server in a while but I checked the last one I did and in the mx record the hostname was mail.domainname.org (and there was only one entry) and the address in the mx record was the same as the address in the mail.domainname.org dns entry.

I could understand if there were two MX records for either load balancing or fail-over in case the main server went down but the setup seems strange and the fact that the mail.domainname.com dns entry doesn't point to the same address as the mx record makes me think something is setup wrong in their email system. Does anyone have some insight into this?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault, but it's perfectly valid to have MX records pointing somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

`mail.domainname.com` has nothing to do with MX or SMTP; it's just a normal domain name.
It typically points to an HTTP server that serves webmail, which may or may not be the same as the SMTP server.

The point of having multiple MX records is in case one of them goes down.

Answer (score 0):

In a DNS zone file, there are different entries that denote the type of service for which a canonical may be directed. One of these is the MX record which determines where services look for email SMTP access. The primary record is called the A record, which usually directs to the IP address(s) for web services and the primary domain.

Hope this helps!